# Importing managed dependencies from another POM with maven

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a POM that describes a set of dependencies in it's dependencyManagement section.  This set of dependencies defines what dependencies will be *provided* when I deploy my application so I want to stick to this list and not have my project redefine them.

**Is there a way that I can inherit the managed dependencies from this POM without it being the parent POM of my project?**

I would like to avoid specifying versions etc in my project POM.

Comment: I think I understand what you're after, but wouldn't it be better then to add them into the dependencymanagement section of your parent pom? Whatever you stick in there will be adopted by all modules of that parent. Perhaps you want finer grained control though. And a side note: be careful with your tags; you should only tag what the question is about, and this has nothing to do with 'cq5' or 'aem'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     ...
     <dependency>
       <groupId>someGroupId</groupId>
       <artifactId>someArtifactId</artifactId>
       <version>someVersion</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency> 
     ...
   </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

You could define this e.g. in your parent POM.